# Access a field containing a space in a template

Tags: templates, go

I am trying to figure out how I can access a map field in a template that contains a space in Go. But I can't seem to figure this out..

I have decoded a JSON array from another source that I don't control like so:

```
var f []interface{}
json.Unmarshal(externalData, &f)
```

Then I pass it to ExecuteTemplate as follows:

```
templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "templates/data.html", map[string]interface{} { "Data": f })
```

In my template I use this:

```
<table>
{{range $element := .Data}}
<tr><td>{{$element.Name}}</td><td>{{$element.**Some Field With Spaces**}}</tr>
{{end}}
</table>
```

And that is where it goes wrong. I guess I can solve this by renaming the "Some Field With Spaces" key manually before sending the data to the template but I'd like to keep it as is. I figure I could probably also make a template function that returns the right key name but that doesn't seem like a very good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{index $element "some field with spaces"}}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/ANNJG1AoVB)

Comment: Wait.. What, I tried this, I must have done something wrong? :-( Thanks though, it works now!